# Best way to querying a list by group by in 1 to n relation entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, group-by, entity-framework-core

I wanted a query to show only the last position of all my workers in a list.
I know that I must use group by for this situation but I don't know what is the best way to do that. I used a lot of way to do that but I think something is wrong plus I had problems with ToListAsync() with group by and I prefer to using queryable for querying instead of enumerable for best performance.As I searched in two or three days ago, I figured out that group by doesn't work with includes and some other problems.
This my code :

```cs
 public class WorkerTaxi : Worker
    {
        #region MainProperties

        ........

        #endregion

        #region EFRelations

        ......

        [InverseProperty(property: "WorkerTaxi")]
        public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty(property: "WorkerTaxi")]
        public virtual ICollection<Position> Positions { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }
```

```cs
 public class Position
    {
        [Required]
        public Guid PositionId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public double GeoLocationLat { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public double GeoLocationLong { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("PersonId")]
        [InverseProperty(property: "Positions")]
        public virtual WorkerTaxi WorkerTaxi{get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Guid PersonId { get; set; }

    }
```

```cs
public async Task<ReadOnlyCollection<PositionViewModel>> 
   GetAllWorkerTaxiLastPositionByCityAsync(string cityName)
    {
        var hashing = new Hashing(text: cityName);
        var hash = hashing.GetHash();
        var workerList = await (from x in _workerTaxi.Include(x=>x.Positions)
                where hashing.GetHashFromEncryption(x.City.CityName) == hash && x.IsReadyForWork
                select x)
            .ToListAsync();
        var workerWithLastPositions = workerList.GroupBy(
            p => p.PersonId,
            p => p.Positions.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Date).FirstOrDefault(),
            (key, g) => new Position{ PersonId = key,GeoLocationLat= g.FirstOrDefault().GeoLocationLat,GeoLocationLong = g.FirstOrDefault().GeoLocationLong }).ToList();
        return _mapper.Map<ReadOnlyCollection<PositionViewModel>>(workerWithLastPositions);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's forget about Entity Framework and `async` and work with the data model.

`Positions` is an `ICollection` which implies no particular order.  So to get the last position of a taxi

```
Positions
  .Where(p => p.WorkerTax == ...)
  .OrderByDescending(p => p.Date)
  .First()
```

As you stated, we can group the positions by taxis and then take the last position.

```
Positions
  .OrderByDescending(p => p.Date)
  .GroupBy(p => p.taxi)
  .Select(g => g.First())
```

A position contains the `taxi`, so to that'all you need.  You have now obtained the last position of all taxis.

Comment: Thank you . it's worked like a charm.
I didn't pay attention that I can do this vice versa :D